# Woocommerce attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this type of attribute in woocommerce

[image]

and I want it like the below image

[image]

I have parent child concept in attribute term but not have it in add product.

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Is there anything within the code that differentiates this from the parent. ie a different class? Providing some source code may help us here.

Comment: It is using li for both parent and child

Comment: can you post the code that outputs the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know exactly that Jelly Bean is going to be the 2nd li in the list, you can use a selector:

```
li:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Compatibility:
IE9+
Firefox 3.5+
Chrome
Safari

If you care about older IE browser you need to solve it in another way :)